# Not able to read a Wordpress RSS feed using ColdFusion

Tags: wordpress, coldfusion, rss

I am using the code below to read an RSS feed from a Wordpress site (3.9.1). It was working fine till yesterday.

---

```
<cftry>
    <!--- dummy url ---> 
    <cfset rssUrl = "http://www.testsite.com/?feed=rss2">
    <cffeed action="read" source="#rssUrl#" query="entriesNews" properties="info" timeout = "180">
    <ul>
    <cfoutput query="entriesNews" startrow="1" maxrows="3">
        <cfset tempTextNews = #title#>
        <cfif len(tempTextNews) gt 75'>
            <li><a class="NewsEvents" href="#rssLink#" target="_blank">#Left(tempTextNews, 75)#...more</a></li>
        <cfelse>
            <li><a class="NewsEvents" href="#rssLink#" target="_blank">#title#...more</a></li>
        </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
    <cfcatch type="any">
       <!--  <cfdump var="#entriesNews#"> --->
       <!--  <cfdump var="#info#"> --->                           
       News Feed Temporarily Unavailable
    </cfcatch>
    </ul>
</cftry>
```

---

I am using a fake url www.testsite.com for posting, instead of the actual website providing the feed. However, I have confirmed the actual url returns a valid RSS feed using http://validator.w3.org/feed/

If I use a browser, I can see the feeds. Using a feed reader in Google Chrome browser, I can notice the feeds load correctly.

I had to comment   and  as ColdFusion did not recognize the "info" and "entriesNews" variables.

If the above code is loaded in a page called testfeed.cfm, I get the message "News Feed Temporarily Unavailable". We are using ColdFusion 9 on a Windows server with IIS.

The details of error are

> Detail:   Check if the specified host on the port is accessible.
>
> Message:  Connection refused by the specified host on the specified
>   port.
>
> StackTrace:
>     coldfusion.syndication.FeedReader$ConnectionRefusedException:
>   Connection refused by the specified host on the specified port. at
>   coldfusion.syndication.FeedReader.getInputStream(FeedReader.java:394)

1. What could have caused a working WordPress RSS feed which was parsed correctly by ColdFusion till last week to stop suddenly?
2. How can I resolve the issue?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Probably not the problem, but `<cfif len(tempTextNews) gt 75'>` looks like it should throw a syntax error.

Comment: <cfdump var="#cfcatch#"> might give you some useful information.

Comment: @Chris H, Firstly you will get an error <cfif len(tempTextNews) gt 75'>  correct it by removing extra apostrophe. Second, May be it's an issue with data returned by feed. You may want to validate data returned by feed before you use them. Moreover, I would also do a check between last week data and new data to see what a change.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate a fundamental failure in connecting. Upload a script onto the server with the error that just executes a CFHTTP onto the same URL and see if that succeeds. It could be something as annoying as a Firewall getting in the way